# ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element could not be scrolled into view using GeckoDriver Firefox with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

How can I fix the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <> could not be scrolled into view
```

error when working with Firefox via Selenium?

None of the tips from the site did not help me. I tried all the solutions I could find, including through WebDriverWait and JS. One of the solutions gave:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message: (568, 1215) is out of bounds of viewport width (1283) and height (699)
```

I tried resizing the browser window, which also didn't work.

My code:

```
webdriverDir = "/Users/Admin/Desktop/MyVersion/geckodriver.exe"
home_url = 'https://appleid.apple.com/account/'
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=webdriverDir)
browser.get(home_url)
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("captcha-input").click()
```

A solution that throws a window size error:

```
actions = ActionChains(browser)
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "captcha-input")))
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
element.click()
```

By the way, this same code works perfectly in Chrome. But it's obvious enough.

Answer (score 1):

To send a *character sequence* to the `<captcha-input>` field you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://appleid.apple.com/account#!&page=create')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.captcha-input input.generic-input-field"))).send_keys("JohnTit")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://appleid.apple.com/account#!&page=create')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//captcha-input//input[@class='generic-input-field   form-textbox form-textbox-text  ']"))).send_keys("JohnTit")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: AppleID_CaptchaInput]